# Button in HTML Page isn't clicked with UIWebview in Swift

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

Good day to you all,

I'm working on loading intranet webpage in UIWebview. It has been loaded successfully but for some strange reason, one of the button in the web page isn't clicked, and it doesn't work.

When I tried to open it from the native browser apps I have on my iPhone (Chrome and Safari), everything works well.

The HTML code behind the button as follow:

```
<a id="btnPurchaseAPIS" href="javascript:APIS.setAction();javascript:APIS.check();" onclick="return !APIS.alreadySubmited;">&nbsp;continue</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some observations first:

1. You should avoid javascript calls within `href`
2. You should use a `<button>` element instead of an anchor element, it is more semantically correct to use buttons for actions that do not direct a user to a new page. You can style them with CSS afterwards as needed.

So my solution would be to have an onclick handler for a button:

```js
function clickHandler() {
  if (!APIS.alreadySubmited) {
    APIS.setAction();
    APIS.check();
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="btnPurchaseAPIS" onclick="clickHandler()">continue</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response , i tried to add a button in HTML DOM and add onclick event . still same problem exists . button isn't working after page loading ..